# Is my code sql injectable? Delete users on the same page an admin and regular users share in $_GET

Tags: php, sql, code-injection, sql-delete

Please view the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sfVYCdE9) containing 
 my members.php file.

The idea is:

An admin & regular user view the member list on the same page....

The only difference IS the admin sees more features like the

```
edit | Delete | Make admin
```

So I suppose I was a bit dumb on parsing the deletion of a user through the url `$_GET` and `isset`

I tried to make this code anti sql injectable by redirecting a regular user and exiting the script once `?id=` is ! equal to ""

```
if($_GET['id'] != ""){
    if (has_access($session_user_id, 1) === false) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
    }
$userID = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='".$userID."'";
$query  = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Should I add in a security feature like preg which will stop the script if id= to anything but a number?

Is this even secure?

Here is the code in action on my free web host.

```
1334.3owl.com/members.php?id=
```

NOTICE, If you got to

```
1334.3owl.com/members.php
```

the id isnt set and I see an error

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\Users\Max\Documents\xampp\htdocs\hope\members.php on line 78
```

Hope you guys can help me out!

NOTE:
the page has the function

```
protect();
```

enabled so you need to be logged in to view the page in the first place

I created two demo accounts:

```
demouser
demopass

demouser2
thisisapassword
```

Please login then go to the link

Comment: So, you want us to view the pastebin, login to your demo site, check the issues and report back?

Comment: Any homebrew input sensitization system is likely to fail. Just use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php and be sure it's safe; or better yet use parameterized queries.

Comment: I would definately use a regex to test if the ID is a number or not, since you know the ID must always be a number. It wouldn't be the first time someone can perform SQL injection because of this

Comment: "Is my code sql injectable?" Yep. I can provide the userid `'; arbitrary SQL statements here;--` and it will run my SQL.

Comment: Well u see im not sure... It will check... if the userid is anything but "", Maybe if you left it empty it wouldnt redirect you... so you might be right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `intval()`:

```
$userID = intval($_GET['id']);
```

This will guarantee that $userID will be an integer so no SQL injection is possible. For added security you can should make sure that $userID is non-zero:

```
if (!$userID)
    die();
```

Comment: hmmmmm Okay, So I should make sure only a number is accepted as input, check user rank, redirect, exit script ... just incase. Also do you have any idea on how I can make it not prompt an error is there is no ?id= in the url ?

Comment: Okay, perfect... Also what is the need of making sure the id is a non- 0

Comment: To make it not show the notice, you can do error_reporting(E_ERROR) somewhere in the beginning of the script. Then it will only show errors instead of notices. OR you can put an @ in the beginning of it:
`if(@$_GET['id'] != ""){`

 Intval() returns 0 if the input wasn't a valid number, so in that case you can assume someone is trying something malicious and you can kill the page.

Comment: okay, true I was just wondering if there was a better way of doing it... Does this always happen if someone removes the variable from the url so they just backspace/delete the ?id= part. Cuz than the variable isnt taken from anywhere.... Maybe I could give the variable a value somewhere in the code of 0? Btw im lost on other ways of doing it :P

Comment: @user2551856 You can always use strlen() to see if there's even anything in ?id. For the case where you have `(url)?id=`, strlen($_GET['id']) is equal to 0.